# pass shell parameters to awk does not work

Tags: bash, awk

Why does this work

```
for myfile in `find . -name "R*VER" -mtime +1`
do
   SHELLVAR=`grep ^err $myfile || echo "No error"`
   ECHO $SHELLVAR
done
```

and outputs

```
No error
err ->BIST Login Fail 3922 err 
No error
err ->IR Remote Key 1 3310 err
```

But this does not

```
for myfile in `find . -name "R*VER" -mtime +1`
do
   SHELLVAR=`grep ^err $myfile || echo "No error"`
   awk -v awkvar=${SHELLVAR} '{print awkvar}'
done
```

and outputs

```
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `{print awkvar}' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `awk -v awkvar="${SHELLVAR}" '{print awkvar}'` does not work. The script seems to hang......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does `$SHELLVAR` contain a space? If so, your awk script is getting misparsed, and the `{print awkvar}` is being assumed to be a file name and not the actual AWK program.

You also have a problem where both your *for* loop and the *awk* program are both slurping STDIN. In fact, your for loop would only be executed once since the AWK will read in all the STDIN until it finishes. In the end, you'll get the same line over and over, and then your program will stop running as the `awk` awaits for more STDIN.

I think you want to do something like this...

```
find . -name "R*VER" -mtime +1 | while read myfile
do
    echo "$SHELLVAR" | awk '{print $0}'
done
```

This way, your echo command feeds into your awk which will prevent awk from reading from the find statement.

As an aside, you're better off doing this:

```
find . -name "R*VER" -mtime +1 | while read myfile
do
   ...
done
```

Rather than this:

```
for myfile in `find . -name "R*VER" -mtime +1`
do
   ...
done
```

This is for several reasons:

1. The command line buffer could overflow, and you'll lose file names, but you'll never see an error.
2. The find command in the second example must first complete before the for loop can start to execute. In the first example, the find feeds into the while loop.

---

### ADDENDUM

Now that I saw [just-my-correct-opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/282658/just-my-correct-opinion)'s answer, I realize what you've really done wrong: You forgot the file name in the `awk` command:

```
find . -name "R*VER" -mtime +1 | while read myfile
do
   SHELLVAR=`grep ^err $myfile || echo "No error"`
   awk -v awkvar=${SHELLVAR} '{print awkvar}' $myfile
done
```

Now, the question is what exactly are you doing with the `awk`. You're not printing anything except the value of `$SHELVAR` for each and every line in the file. That's probably not what you want to do. In fact, why not simply do this:

```
find . -name "R*VER" -mtime +1 | while read myfile
do
   SHELLVAR=$(grep -q "^err" $myfile")
   if [ "x$SHELLVAR" != "x" ]
   then
      echo "$SHELLVAR"
   fi
done
```

That way, you print out `$SHELLVAR`, but only if `$SHELLVAR` is empty.

Or, you can use awk to print out only those lines that match your regex:

```
find . -name "R*VER" -mtime +1 | while read myfile
do
   awk '/^err/ {print $0}' $myfile
done
```

Comment: I changed my code to a while loop and fed $myfile to the awk command. It worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

What you're trying to do is possible but ... a bit quirky.  Here's an alternative for you:

```
for f in $(find . -name "R*VER" -mtime +1)
do
    echo "$f"
    awk 'BEGIN{ec=0} /^err/{ec+=1;print} END{if(ec==0){print "No error"}}' "$f"
done
```

This way you don't have to worry about `grep`, don't have to worry about shell variables and can keep your logic all in one place in one language.

Note that this code is only partially tested since I don't have your data files, but the testing I did worked fine.

If you'd like you can even go a step farther and write the whole thing in `awk`.  It is, after all, a full, general-purpose programming language (with, IMO, a far cleaner syntax than `bash`).  This way you avoid the need for `find`, `grep` and `bash` entirely.  I won't be writing that script, however.  You'll have to pick up the `awk` man page and read up on file I/O yourself.

Comment: Ah! That's what's missing! The name of the file to parse.

Answer (score 4):

You need to quote `$SHELLVAR`, to prevent the shell from splitting it.

```
awk -v awkvar="${SHELLVAR}" '{print awkvar}'
```

Comment: I made the mod you suggest and now, the script sits there and does nothing:

awk -v awkvar="${SHELLVAR}" '{print awkvar}'



What gives?

Comment: After posting, I realized there were more things wrong with your script. There is no input to `awk`. Did you really mean that? If so, use `'BEGIN{print awkvar}'`.

Comment: DISCLAIMER: I am self taught (no kidding, huh?). How can there no input to awk when 1) I initialize the bash variable `SHELLVAR` and pass it to my Awk program with `awk -v awkvar="${SHELLVAR}"`???

Comment: What @ninjalj is saying is that `awk` will normally try to process from standard input and execute the code block for each line it reads. But you're not giving it anything to read from. The `BEGIN` change he suggested works.

Answer (score 1):

You have already got alternative solutions. Regardless of that, I just want to answer your question, ie the thing that you are missing:

`awk -v awkvar=${SHELLVAR} '{print awkvar}'`

**Here awk is seeking to read the input from `STDIN`. And that's the problem.** Awk seeks to read input from `STDIN`, unless you specify input file(s). The given commands to awk are executed for each `RECORD` in the input (and by default a record is a line). See `man awk` to read more on awk.

But here is a hack, if you want it to proceed without any input:

`awk -v awkvar=${SHELLVAR} 'BEGIN{print awkvar}'`

BEGIN block is executed as soon as the `awk` is called. And if `awk` doesn't find any other block except `BEGIN`, it executes those `BEGIN` blocks and exits.

*I hope you got the problem behind the error, and a quick solution for that as well.*